# Laravel. Driver [instagram] not supported. Cannot handle the callback response

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

I'm working on Instagram API and I want to make auth via Instagram. The first step of it - redirect user to IG page.
I'm redirecting

```
return redirect()->away('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='. $this->client_id .'&redirect_uri='. url('instagram/login/callback') .'&response_type=code');
```

When I log in I get an error - Driver [instagram] not supported

I already wrote IG API credentials in my services.php, ENV file. I created client in instagram website. But everytime, when user loggin in and redirecting back - he gets this error. I'm googling 2 days. I even used 2-3 packages from github for Instagram, but I'm still getting the same error. I cleared caches with every possible ways - all php artisan clear commands, manually deleting cache from /bootstrap dir.

The FB API works perfect, but not this.

Here is my configs:

**.env**

```
INSTAGRAM_ID=54c582bd3ea944b78f741c8aac3001ce
INSTAGRAM_SECRET=4a3***********8c
```

**services.php**

```
'instagram' => [
        'client_id' => env('INSTAGRAM_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('INSTAGRAM_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => '/instagram/login/callback',
    ],
```

**InstagramController.php**

```
class InstagramController extends Controller
{
    private $client_id;

    private $client_secret;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->client_id = config('services.instagram.client_id');
        $this->client_secret = config('services.instagram.client_secret');

    }



    /**
     * Show Instagram API submit page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function getAPIPage(Request $request){

        return redirect()
            ->away('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?
             client_id='. $this->client_id .'&redirect_uri='. 
             url('instagram/login/callback') .'&response_type=code');
         }
}
```

I'm using Laravel Socialite.

What can I do else?

Comment: are you using laravel socialite ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Socialite

Comment: have u added ? `\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
`

Comment: Yes yes. I said FB is working perfectly

Comment: Do  some cache  and config clear, I remember I had such error with `linkedin`  after some time the error was gone

Comment: As I said - I did all possible cache clearings

Comment: Why are you constructing the oauth URL yourself, instead of `return Socialite::driver('instagram')->redirect();`?

Comment: Furthermore, socialite does not support instagram out of the box, you need to use the instagram provider from https://socialiteproviders.github.io/ -- have you installed that?

Comment: @sam, I installed it and nothing was changed. Also I user this function too.

Comment: Did you install it by following all the instructions, including adding the event listeners and using the `redirect` method? If yes, and you're still experiencing issues, please update the question with the code you're now using.

Comment: @sam thank you for your response. No, I didn't included listener functionality, only two classes (class and provider)

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan you need to follow the documentation exactly, you're required to include the listeners to be able to use the provider. Please start over, following [the installation instructions in the documentation exactly](https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/instagram), and then if you continue to have any issues help can be offered -- but until you've followed the installation process properly, we can't help.

Comment: @sam thank you. I'll be able to get response to you after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

@sam told me to do all things from instructions. I didn't add the listener events before, but when I added it - API worked. I didn't understand why, but we need to add listener classes in EventServiceProvider.php.

Do step by step:
http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/instagram/